# Vue.js 3 call anonymous function inside event handler

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Is it possible to call an anonymous function inside the event handler on Vue.js 3?

I found these options across the internet:

```
<button @click="return function() { console.log('test')}()">Click me</button>

<button @click="() => { console.log('test') }">Click me</button> //ES6

<button @click="(function(){ console.log('Test'); })();">Click me</button>
```

None of them seems to be working. Maybe they used to work with Vue.js 2 but I can't confirm that.

Comment: It's a bad practice to write the code in a template, that's what script block is for. This breaks the separation of concerns and  results in poorly maintainable and debuggable code. This has been so since AngularJS, which Vue borrows from a lot

Comment: I am aware that is a bad practice but it is just for my mockup/demo design that will be changed later on.

Comment: This approach not very practical in Vue for the reason explained in the answer. Vue doesn't provide the access to globals from a template, particularly for security reasons, I guess

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `console` is not defined in the template, so you should define it as property in your data, or call a method that use the `console` :

```html
<button @click="() => { logDatat('some data log') }">Click me</button> 

<button @click="() => { myConsole.log }">Click me</button> 

....

data(){
  return {
     myConsole : console
   }
}
```

The three syntaxes are valid as shown in this demo :

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/NWMWdMe)